# MouseListener is not responding as expected

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

I can not figure out why the MouseListener is not responding. I have three classes-

ButtonGr.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonGr extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private String s;
public ButtonGr(){
JRadioButton line=new JRadioButton("line");
line.setActionCommand("line");
line.setSelected(true);

JRadioButton rectangle=new JRadioButton("rectangle");
rectangle.setActionCommand("rectangle");
JRadioButton ellipse=new JRadioButton("ellipse");
ellipse.setActionCommand("ellipse");
JRadioButton circle=new JRadioButton("circle");
circle.setActionCommand("circle");

ButtonGroup g=new ButtonGroup();
g.add(line);
g.add(rectangle);
g.add(ellipse);
g.add(circle);

add(line);
add(rectangle);
add(ellipse);
add(circle);

line.addActionListener(this);
rectangle.addActionListener(this);
ellipse.addActionListener(this);
circle.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
s=e.getActionCommand();
}
public String getSou(){
return s;
}
}
```

MouseEven.java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MouseEven implements MouseListener{
private String s;
private static int a;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
s=e.getX()+" "+e.getY();
countEvent(e);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
s=e.getX()+" "+e.getY();
countEvent(e);
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
s=e.getX()+" "+e.getY();
countEvent(e);
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
s=e.getX()+" "+e.getY();
countEvent(e);
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
s=e.getX()+" "+e.getY();
countEvent(e);
}

private void countEvent(MouseEvent e){
a++;
}

public String getCor(){
System.out.println(s);
return s;
}

public int getCount(){
System.out.println(a);
return a;
}

}
```

Tester.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Tester{
public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame f=new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container c=f.getContentPane();
ButtonGr bg=new ButtonGr();
c.add(bg,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

JPanel p=new JPanel();
p.setBackground(new Color(250,250,250));
JLabel l=new JLabel("view");
p.add(l);
MouseEven me=new MouseEven();
p.addMouseListener(me);
c.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
f.setSize(600,500);
f.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(me.getCor());
System.out.println(me.getCount());
}

}
```

I want it to write co-ordinates of the cursor on the console. When it is done, I will use it for another purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is printed coordinates to the console is the `getCor()`method. And it's only called once, in the main method, once you've built your frame. If you want to print the coordinates every time they change, then you should... do just that: print the corrdinates from your mouse listener methods.

Also, please indent your code, and choose better names for your methods, variables and classes. `s` and `a` are very poor names. `ButtonGr` is much less readable than `ButtonGroup`. `getCor` is much less readable than `getCoordinates`